# using random forest for categorical inference

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Let's say you have a response variable y and 2 predictor variables x1 and x2. Your goal is to make inferences about the x2 predictor which is a categorical variable that contains the group (A,B,C,D...Z) that an observation belongs to. You want to answer the question: which groups move the response variable more/less than others.

Note: x1 is a continuous predictor that you want to control for.

You can run fixed effect model (using lm() ) or random effect (using lme4() or a bayesian stan) model to get some understanding of how the groups affect the outcome. In those cases you would get 26 coefficients if using the fixed effect model, 26 random effects if using the random effects models (stan or lme4).

My question is can you use a machine learning algorithm like random forest or neural networks to make inferences on the groups. Let's say you chose random forest how could set up the solution to make inferences that one group increases/decreases the response variable more or less similar to what the coefficients in linear models and the random effects in random effect models indicate?

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, you will NOT have 26 random effects - you are just estimating 1 variance term. That's an important part of the difference between random and fixed effects.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this before, but I might try to do the following.  Use a random forest implementation that handles categorical splits properly (I think the r implementation might).  This is an open ticket for scikit-learn here's the [ticket](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4899).

Once the random forest has been trained you can examine all splits in the categorical variable of interest. You would be looking for which groups of categories had the largest decrease in impurity.